# How do I keep Logstash running so it syncs data from my RDBMS to ES?

Tags: jdbc, elasticsearch, logstash

I'm a complete newbie to the ELK stack, so please excuse my ignorance. I've been able to get Logstash to send data from my database to Elasticsearch, but it exits once it's done with the transfer. How do I keep it running so it keeps them in sync? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify a [schedule](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-jdbc.html#plugins-inputs-jdbc-schedule) in your `jdbc` input:

The `schedule` below (`* * * * *`) will run every minute and select records from your database and only select the records that have been updated after the last time the query ran. Your `updated` timestamp field might be named differently, feel free to adjust to fit your case.

```
input {
  jdbc {
    jdbc_driver_library => "mysql-connector-java-5.1.36-bin.jar"
    jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb"
    jdbc_user => "mysql"
    parameters => { "some_field" => "value" }
    schedule => "* * * * *"
    statement => "SELECT * from songs WHERE some_field = :some_field AND updated > :sql_last_value"
  }
}
```