# how to get updated rows value in elasticsearch

Tags: sql-server, elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-configuration

I am using ElasticSearch db and connecting sql server db tables using Logstash, I am getting records and able to display in Kibana, but my problem is how should i get updated columns reflect in elasticsearch. As I have updated some column values in SqlServer db tables, but not able to see the updated values in Elasticsearch. Is any config/settings is there to get immediate reflecting of records in elasticsearch.

Thanks.
Raj

Comment: This answer might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38631322/how-do-i-keep-logstash-running-so-it-syncs-data-from-my-rdbms-to-es/38631437#38631437

Comment: Thanks for response, but if my table does not have column "lastmodifieddate" or "lastupdatededate" etc..then in that case what is the solution is there any settings from elasticsearch or logstash . so how should i get updated row data.

Comment: Here is another solution where you can use another column (not necessarily a date): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40378580/using-an-id-of-a-table-for-sql-last-value-in-logstash/40385238#40385238