# can Elasticsearch monitor database table continuously

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch, logstash

I have a transaction table in the MySQL database. Everytime transaction table updates (i.e insert a new record) I want immediately index it into elasticsearch index. I have come across this article [INSERT INTO LOGSTASH SELECT DATA FROM DATABASE](https://www.elastic.co/blog/logstash-jdbc-input-plugin) but it only syncs the database table when the logstash restarted, not continue watching it. Can someone suggest me a way to do this.

Comment: this answer might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38631322/how-do-i-keep-logstash-running-so-it-syncs-data-from-my-rdbms-to-es/38631437#38631437

Comment: This solved my problem, thank you